# Naming the PDF after exporting with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code which gets data from a sheet and populates a form. Within the data there are duplicate entries. [Refer to Data img.]

```
Dim i As Long
Dim dataWS As Worksheet, formWS As Worksheet
Dim thisFile As Range, destRange As Range
Dim thisFile2 As Range, destRange2 As Range

FolderPath = "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\PAF_Output\"

MkDir FolderPath

Set dataWS = Sheets("Data")
Set formWS = Sheets("Form")
For i = 2 To 5

Set thisFile2 = dataWS.Range("A" & i) 
Set destRange2 = formWS.Range("B4:I4")
thisFile2.Copy destRange2

Set thisFile = dataWS.Range("B" & i) 
Set destRange = formWS.Range("O4:Q4")
thisFile.Copy destRange

Sheets(Array("Form")).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=FolderPath & thisFile2.Value & ".pdf", _
openafterpublish:=False, ignoreprintareas:=False


Next i

End Sub
```

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiT6N.jpg)

As you can see from

```
FileName:=FolderPath & thisFile2.Value & ".pdf"
```

The files are named after the values from column A. Nonetheless, in the case of the duplicate entries, excel will override the first file with the second one. What I'm trying to do is now create a name combining the names of the values within Column A and the arrival date values in Column B. Like this...

```
FileName:=FolderPath & thisFile2.Value & thisFile.Value & ".pdf"
```

This throws me an error though. Can someone help me please?

Comment: The problem is probably "/" in the filenames - try formatting without.

Comment: @SJR Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to format your date so the slashes (/) don't appear, as filenames cannot contain these characters, as below, also worth mentioning that you are copying from a single cell and pasting into a range, which I doubt is what you wanted to achieve..:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim dataWS As Worksheet: Set dataWS = Sheets("Data")
Dim formWS As Worksheet: Set formWS = Sheets("Form")
Dim thisFile As Range, destRange As Range
Dim thisFile2 As Range, destRange2 As Range

FolderPath = "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\PAF_Output\"

MkDir FolderPath

For i = 2 To 5
    Set thisFile2 = dataWS.Range("A" & i)
    Set destRange2 = formWS.Range("B4:I4")
    thisFile2.Copy destRange2

    Set thisFile = dataWS.Range("B" & i)
    Set destRange = formWS.Range("O4:Q4")
    thisFile.Copy destRange

    formWS.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=FolderPath & thisFile2.Value & Format(thisFile.Value, "MM-dd-yyyy") & ".pdf", openafterpublish:=False, ignoreprintareas:=False
Next i
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

To tidy up the code a little more and remove not needed statements, like the copy and paste, please see below:

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Long
Dim dataWS As Worksheet: Set dataWS = Sheets("Data")
Dim formWS As Worksheet: Set formWS = Sheets("Form")

FolderPath = "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\PAF_Output\"

If Dir(FolderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir FolderPath
'above if the folder doesn't exist then create it

For i = 2 To 5
    formWS.Range("B4:I4") = dataWS.Range("A" & i)
    formWS.Range("O4:Q4") = dataWS.Range("B" & i)
    'above transfer the values from one range to another without copying

    formWS.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=FolderPath & thisFile2.Value & Format(thisFile.Value, "MM-dd-yyyy") & ".pdf", openafterpublish:=False, ignoreprintareas:=False
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Makes sense. I didn't think of that. Thank you for providing the written syntax. Thank you!

Comment: A small point - you could take two of the range variables out of the loop.

Comment: @SJR yes of course you could, but I have a niggling doubt that this is what the OP wanted to achieve as I've rarely seen anyone copy a single cell into a range, so I thought I'd leave it as it was because I'm not sure what the point of it is.... :)

Comment: @Xabier         It probably can be improved A LOT MORE. I'm an amateur with VBA so baby steps. More than welcome to talk to you in a chat room! Thank you again!

Comment: @ChunkyFresh I've updated my answer to show how I would probably go about it, an If statement to check whether the folder actually exists before going ahead to create it and transferring values from one range to another without using .Copy, hope this helps a little... :)